apt-get update fails to fetch files, Temporary failure resolving
i just installed ubuntu and tried sudo apt update as my first command but i get these errors


Are you connected to the Internet?

I faced the same issue, turned out I was connected to a VPN, check if you are too, also might wanna check your DNS as well!
